# Django User.date_joined.date using UTC time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

In my template, I want to show the join date of a user, so I am using `{{ user.date_joined }}` which shows the date and time (in local time zone - same as what is shown in the admin panel). To just show the date, I use `{{ user.date_joined.date }}`, but it seems to be converting the date and time to UTC before showing the date (I am in EST/EDT - I never remember which is which).

For example:

`{{ user.date_joined }}` ==> Feb. 18, 2021, 7 p.m.

`{{ user.date_joined.date }}` ==> Feb. 19, 2021

Is there a way for me to change this so that it shows the same date as the full date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution/workaround for anyone else with a similar question.
Instead of using `{{ user.date_joined.date }}` like a traditional datetime object, I used `{{ user.date_joined|date }}`